# Mapping of equivalence classes of integers modulo $n$

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

This is an exercise problem from *Essentials of Discrete Mathematics (3rd Edition)* by David J. Hunter. The problem is as follows:

> Consider the function $p : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n$ defined by $p(k) = [k]$. Prove that this function is onto but not one-to-one.

The answer is given as follows:

> Onto: For any $[n], p(n) = [n]$. It is not one-to-one (for $n \neq 0$) because $p(0) = [0] = p(n)$.

I would be most grateful if someone could elaborate more upon this given answer.

From my understanding, for any given equivalence class $[k]_n$ for the set of integers modulo $n$, 
\begin{align}
[k]_n &= \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} : x \equiv k\bmod{n}\} \\
&= \{\cdots, k-n, k, k+n, \cdots \}
\end{align}
In which case, I am not sure why $[0]$ does not satisfy the quality of being one-to-one.

EDIT: Thank you very much to all the answers. I am very dumb, the answer was staring at me right in the face.

Comment: $p(k+n)=p(k)$ but $k+n\ne k.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $[n] = [0]$, but $n \not=0$.  This is why is it not 1-1; it does not preserve distinctness. Remember your domain is the integers.

Answer (score 0):

The function is onto because any $[k] \in \mathbb{Z}/n$ is a value of the function $p$, namely $p(k) = [k]$. It is not one-to-one because $n \neq 0$ but $p(n) = [n]=[0]=p(0)$, two different elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ have the same image.